# SQL join multiple tables with same column names into a new table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 12 tables where I need to combine 5 of the columns into a new table.

Each table is a different month but they all have the same column names.

I believe I need to use 11 join's, but when I use left join, I'm returning data only from the first table(jan). When I use full outer join I am returning rows full of Null's but looks like merged tables. I am using BigQuery.

```
SELECT 
  jan.ride_id, 
  jan.member_casual,
  jan.ride_length, 
  jan.day_of_week,
  jan.rideable_type
FROM 
  `jan_22` as jan 
  left join `feb_22` as feb 
  on jan.ride_id= feb.ride_id
```

The result I'm looking for is the 5 columns with data from all 12 tables merged. Just trying to merge the first 2 correctly before adding the others.

Also should I use select into or insert into for creating a new table with the 5 columns?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No! You do not need JOINs! Instead you need UNION ALLs! With maybe one more extra column identifying month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Mikhail Berlyant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221944/mikhail-berlyant) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72734918/sql-join-multiple-tables-with-same-column-names-into-a-new-table#comment128473632_72734918) you should use `union` as the difference between `join` and `union` is that `join` joins a table horizontally and `union` joins vertically. And as you need 5 columns you should join them using `union` as follows:

```sql
insert dataset.new_table(<the columns(6)>)
SELECT 
  'Jan' as Month_Name,
  jan.ride_id, 
  jan.member_casual,
  jan.ride_length, 
  jan.day_of_week,
  jan.rideable_type
FROM 
  `jan_22` as jan 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  'Feb',
  feb.ride_id, 
  feb.member_casual,
  feb.ride_length, 
  feb.day_of_week,
  feb.rideable_type
FROM `feb_22` as feb 
...
```

And as you probably have rows that return duplicate values it will be ignored by `union` but not by `union all` so you should use `union all`.

See here in [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#insert_select_statement) how to `insert` into a table using `select` statement.

Comment: Without insert into query is running exactly how I needed. Thank you so much. 

Just  getting error for insert into- "new_table" must be qualified with dataset. It looks like this:

insert into 

new_table(ride_id, member_casual, ride_length, day_of_week, rideable_type)

Comment: Did you add a column for the month name? I'm editing my answer with a link reference.

Comment: I viewed the link, and added the dataset name right before new_table(<columns>) . I am now getting a * Not found: Dataset cyclistic-1738:cyclistic-1738 was not found in location US*

I'm using BigQuery. the location is US. My data is uploaded to GCS, so I pulled the data from that bucket. Does this issue have to do with permissions? I tried changing from Uniform to API's but still getting error.

Comment: This probably doesn't have anything to do with the `insert`. You can ask a new question or search for this error.